# Retrieve all labels on a table

Tags: google-bigquery

Big query metadata information are very useful when your data environnement contains thousand of objects.
Howewer, a specific metadata information is difficult to retrieve : labels on a Big Query table
Indeed, request result provide inexploitable result as a table like this :

*`[STRUCT("visibility", "nan"), STRUCT("author", "nan"), STRUCT("deprecated", "nan"), STRUCT("project", "nan"), STRUCT("version", "nan"), STRUCT("wip", "nan")]`*

Request :

```
create table dwh_meta.tata as SELECT table_name,option_value FROM dwh_meta.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS WHERE option_name="labels"
```

My question is how could I for each table retrieve these informations in a STRUCT field containing 2 fields like this :

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS3Xb.png)

Comment: Have you tried to use bq query command? `bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 
'SELECT   * FROM mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS WHERE option_name="labels"'` and then save the result to the table?

Comment: Hi, I tried but as mentionned, it provides inexploitable result. On esolution would be to parse string field with JSON formatter. I work on it !

Comment: As I can understand, you've found a solution with JSON formater?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71144405/how-can-i-unnest-a-string-of-an-array-of-structs-in-bigquery/) question shows how to parse stringified array of structs in the `option_value` column of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS`: consider

```
array(
  select as struct arr[offset(0)] key, arr[offset(1)] value
  from unnest(regexp_extract_all(option_value, r'STRUCT\(("[^"]+", "[^"]+")\)')) kv, 
  unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ', ') as arr)]) 
)
```